# Why can't I access JavaScript array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
  <script>      
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "yep.php", 
   data: { 'cars' : cars}, 
   success: function() { 
          alert("Success"); 
    } 
   }); 
  </script>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
  <?php
     $myArray = $_POST['cars'];
     var_dump($myArray);
 ?>`
```

It is displaying success message, so it means array was passed to php
then it shows:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cars in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\yep.php on line 18
NULL
```

Why is it returning null for array?

Comment: You've shown 4 lines of PHP code, but indicated that the error is on line 18.

Comment: maybe you should try to debug your code by yourself first ; why var_dump on $myArray and not on `$_POST` ? maybe your js array is never posted

Comment: your javascript code and php code is in same file? if yes then put your php code into some check like `if(isset($_POST['cars'])){  $myArray = $_POST['cars'];
     var_dump($myArray); die;}`

Comment: @uditrawat
 I have putted that in code and then it only gave success message and nothing else
means the if condition was false, so somehow js array  wasn't send to php

Comment: @GregSchmidt 
  l have not posted html and head tags. I have wrote all this code in one file yep.php 
line 18 is $myArray = $_POST['cars'];

Comment: @Pierre
 if js array is never posted then it would have not given success message

Comment: if you say so...

Comment: What is the Content-Type in the Request Header of the POST request to yep.php? You should be able to see that in the browser console, Network tab. You could get that result if the Content-Type is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus 
If you don't mind, can u elaborate

Comment: `{ cars : cars}, ` **without quotes**

Comment: @Roy
 didn't worked

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not firing any event like click event, try this code and let me know is it working or not for you.

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="submit">

  <script>      
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  $('input[type=button]').click({
      $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "yep.php", 
   data: { 'cars' : cars}, 
   success: function(data) { 
          alert("Success");
          console.log(data);
          $("body").empty().html('Ajax Response:<br />'+data);
    } 
   }); 
  })
  </script>

 <?php
     $myArray = $_POST['cars'];
     var_dump($myArray);
 ?>`
```

Comment: Its not working, its not even giving alert so probably array is not passed from js to php
its giving output as
Notice: Undefined index: cars in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\firstprogram.php on line 26 which is $myArray = $_POST['cars'];
NULL

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       url: "yep.php", 
       data: { 'cars' : cars}, 
       success: function() { 
              alert("Success"); 
        } 
}); 
  </script>
   </html>
<?php
$myArray = $_POST['cars'];
var_dump($myArray);
?>

Comment: @Amateur the code provided in this response is correct, you on the other hand are showing an error from another file, `firstprogram.php`. If you want the `cars` to be available in `firstprogram.php` you must include that file in `yep.php`. FYI PHP is executed ONCE(per request) and everything included in the main file is processed in a synchronous matter.

Comment: @Amateur `var_dump($myArray)` won't appear in your browser window. To see the output, open **Developer Tools**  from your browser, select the **Network** tab, click on the request to `/yep.php` and then click the **Response** tab

Comment: @darklightcode
 if i want to print it on screen using php then what can I do? 
usually isn't var_dump() used to print on screen?

Comment: you have to receive response from backend in success function of ajax and can show on web page or console , alert and html tags(using append , prepend etc function of jquery)

Comment: @Amateur No, PHP doesn't know/care if you have a screen or not, `var_dump`, `print_r`,`echo`,`sprintf` w/e, can be used to output the evaluated contents, in your case, the webserver acts as an intermediary, it sends the client(browser) request to PHP, then it gets processed and it may or may not produces an output which will be sent back to the client who made the request. When making requests using `Ajax`, the requests are sent in parallel, think of them as hidden requests, you don't need to refresh/submit the browser for a new output. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you a bunch of data and you want to submit all once, then you need to create and empty object and append values to it. This will be the case, if for some reasons you don't want to use `var form = new FormData(this.form);`
For example:

```
<script>      
  var cars = {};
  cars['value1'] = 'Value 1';
  cars['value2'] = 'Value 2';
  cars['value3'] = 'Value 3';

  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "yep.php", 
  data: { cars : cars}, 
  success: function(data) { 
      console.log(data); 
  } 
 }); 
</script>
```

But your case is simple, just do it like this in your `data:`

```
<script>      
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "yep.php", 
  data: { cars : cars}, 
  success: function(data) { 
      console.log(data); 
  } 
 }); 
</script>
```

The first one is the direct method, but this one is the JSON method.

in jquery first do this...

```
var array_fields = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var cars = JSON.stringify( array_fields );
```

Then In PHP do this...

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['cars']);
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: `$myArray = $_POST['cars'];` use this instead and check `print_r($myArray);`

Answer (score 1):

The error message comes *before the script is even executed*! Suggest two small changes so you can see what's going on.

In the script:

```
success: function(data) { 
          alert(data); 
    }
```

This will show what is being returned from the ajax call. From the [jQuery.ajax doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server,.....

In the php:

```
<?php 
  if (!isset($_POST['cars'])) {
      echo "Wait for it";
      } 
  else {
      $myArray = $_POST['cars']; var_dump($myArray);
      } 
  ?>
```

Now you will notice

1. That `Wait for it` is displayed in the browser, instead of the error
   message
2. In the alert box you will see  the *entire output* of
   `yep.php` is being returned. Scroll down to see the data
   as you expect.

IMO the place to start  is to split this into two scripts. The first an html  that does not include the php. The second, the php that will be requested from the script.

Comment: After making above changes it is showing whole code except php part in alert message.
Split this into two scripts that means make two files, one with .html extension and one with .php extension 
I did, but after that on opening html file it was blank, in browser console>Network>yep.php it showed Failed to load response data

Comment: I copied the code from a comment posted above. I had to change the `<script>` line for jquery to this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.  With the exception of that line, I split the exact code into an html (yep.html) and a php (yep.php). I browsed to yep.html in Firefox. And got expected response data. Local web server is IIS. Opening the html file will be blank, there's nothing to render. Did you check browser console for errors?